# Why MSI GS63 8RD-004TH cannot install ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, drivers, 18.04

My GS63 8RD-004TH always freeze after finished installation and I have to hard shutdown. I try ubuntu 16.04, 18.04 even debian but the result is still the same. What should I do or where should I report this issue?.